# destruir mi sesion con php y javascript

Tags: php, session

En la vista tengo la opción de eliminar un empleado. Cuando lo elimino, me llevo su id a mi archivo js para allí eliminarlo de forma asíncrona. Quiero que cuando este sea eliminado, la sesión se destruya y me redireccione al index. Estoy haciendo un sesion_destroy() en el controlador después de eliminar el registro, pero no hace nada. Lo elimina y la sesión se queda abierta. Esto es lo que tengo:

```
 echo  "<div class='plans' id='employer-plan'>";?>

        <div class='plan'>
            <img class='foto' src='../img/<?php echo $datosEmpleado->getFoto() ?>'>
            <ul class='datos-empleado'>
                <li><strong>DEPARTAMENTO: </strong><?php echo $datosEmpleado->getDepartamento() ?></li>
                <li><strong>EMAIL: </strong> <?php echo $datosEmpleado->getEmail() ?> </li>
            </ul>
            <a href='../views/empleadoEditar.php?id=<?php echo $datosEmpleado->getId() ?>'>
            <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
            </a>

           //Aquí es donde recojo el id de mi empleado:

            <a  data_id_employer='<?php echo $datosEmpleado->getId() ?>' class='employer-plans-delete' href='#'><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php
        echo "</div>";
```

Esta es mi función js:

```
    function eliminarEmpleado(e) {

    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('employer-plans-delete')) {

        const id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data_id_employer');

        console.log(id);

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Está seguro/a?',
            text: "Esta opción no será reversible",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Eliminar'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                //Abrir la conexión
                xhr.open('GET', `../controller/empleadoControlador.php?id=${id}&accion=eliminar`, true);

                //Pasar los datos
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
                    }
                }
                xhr.send();
                Swal.fire(
                    '¡ELIMINADO/A!',
                    'EMPLEADO/A ELIMINADO/A CON ÉXITO',
                    'success'
                )
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Y en mi controlador estoy tratando de desstruir la sesión así:

```
 if (isset($_GET['accion'])) {
    if (($_GET['accion']== 'eliminar')) {
        try {
            $empDao->borrarEmpleado($_GET['id']);
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: index.php');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die("Error".$e->getMessage());
            echo "Error en la línea: ".$e->getLine();
        }
    }
}
```